# Не получается передать правильно массив в вид

Tags: массивы, строки, laravel

Здравствуйте друзья. У меня такая проблема, при передачи массива в вид в виде оно конвертируется в строку как это можно исправить

мой контроллер

```
 $articles = Article::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();

        return view("articles")->with("articles","$articles");
```

если в контроллере написать вот так, массив нормально отображается

```
dump($articles);
```

а в виде если написать вот так

```
{{$articles}}
```

в браузере отображается как строка

> {"id":2,"header":"hi Everyone","short_content":"HI EVERYBODY, HOW ARE
>   YOU","content":"HI, THIS IS MY FIRST ARTICLE, HOPE YOU'LL
>   SATISFITED","created_at":"2017-11-04
>   12:25:18","updated_at":"2017-11-04 15:35:18","user_id":1}

как нормально отобразить массив, чтобы с помощью foreach я смог отобразить например только short_content с массива. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не стоит передавать данные на вид в таком виде как у вас:

```
return view("articles")->with("articles","$articles");
```

Есть несколько способов передать данные на вид в Laravel:

Стандартный вывод:

```
return view('articles', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

Самый удобный и простой (но тут нужно знать как работает функция [compact](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.compact.php)):

```
return view("articles", compact('articles'));
```

Через метод `with`:

```
return view("articles")->with('articles',$articles);
```

Так же если вы хотите вывести только `short_name`, выбирайте только его:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->pluck('short_name');
```

Отображение правильное у вас, потому что вы пытаетесь отобразить коллекцию в виде строки, поэтому коллекция обращается к методу `__toString` который в свою очередь к `__toJson` и вы получаете на выходе JSON.

Чтобы отобразить данные обращайтесь к ним как к простому массиву через тот же `foreach` как и писалось выше, только с учетом того что использовался `pluck` будет следующее:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <p>{{ $article }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в контроллере сделать вот так:

```
return view("articles", compact('articles'));
```

А в шаблоне так:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <p>{{ $article->short_content }}</p>
@endforeach
```